# Picasso wont load images anymore after updating to .get()

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

My app was working fine till i migrated to new version of Picasso, so android studio told me i should change the .with methods to .get() so i changed it and now it won't load images, and doesn't give me any errors, here is my code:

```
Picasso.get().load(image).error(R.drawable.placeholder).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).centerCrop().resize(720,720).into(this.image_view_wallpaper_image);

        public static void imageDownload(Context ctx, String url,String name){
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .into(getTarget(url,name,ctx));
        }
        //target to save
        private static Target getTarget(final String url, final String name, final Context ctx){
            Target target = new Target(){

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.DownloadFolder) + name);
                            try {
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                                ostream.flush();
                                ostream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                    Log.v("ok","onBitmapLoaded");


                }
    public void loadBitmap(String url) {

            if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    tempBmp=bitmap;
                    new WallpaperOperation().execute("");
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }



                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            };
            Picasso.get().load(url).into(loadtarget);
        }
```

before updating it was like this and was working perfectly :

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).error(R.drawable.placeholder).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).centerCrop().resize(720,720).into(this.image_view_wallpaper_image);
```

obviously it's not whole code I just put the sections that I've changed, i didn't get any errors, Picasso is at the latest version but it won't show anything, i also migrated to android x too.

Comment: Can you check only this part `Picasso.get().load(image).error(R.drawable.placeholder).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).centerCrop().resize(720,720).into(this.image_view_wallpaper_image);` and report if it works or not. I just checked your first line and it did load the image from internet.

Comment: @Farid i checked this part but it wont load anything not in my server or not on the internet, i put the direct address too but nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Do you have any part that you've changed when upgrading the library? Also, to check whether the problem is with the current project or not, can you create a new simple project and test Picasso there. If that project works then we can detect problem easily, I guess

Comment: @Farid could this be because of im using http instead of https ? is it related ?

Comment: It's totally related, Picasso won't load from `http` out-of-the-box. Replace your `http` prefix with `https`. I guess, you already know how to do it, but providing it anyway `image.replace("http","https")`. By default, Picasso relies on the existing `http` client if that client is not supporting `http` connections then Picasso won't load iamge

Comment: If you don't want to replace all your urls then add this dependency `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.1")` to `gradle` then Picasso can load image from `http`

Comment: @farid its fixed https , i fixed my server and its loading now

Comment: @Farid write an answer so i can choose it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, problem was http endpoint problem. You have two options:

**Option 1.** Replace your `url`'s http with https beofre passing to Picasso

```
    String imageUrl = "http://www.myurl.com/images/earth.png";
    imageUrl = imageUrl.replace("http","https");
    Picasso.get().url(imageUrl).....
```

**Option 2.** Use a http client that supports Http connections, for example OkHttp. To use it add the dependency to `gradle.build`

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.1")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Glide library instand of Picasso because Glide is faster then Picasso and some other features.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

}

Usage

```
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.mImgProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cart);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .into(holder.mImgProduct);
```

Comment: OP is not asking for alternatives, asking for a solution. Would be better to consider